# Making a ball balancing game with the gyroscope of mobile devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, gyroscope

as the title already says, i'm currently working on a small ball balancing game using the gyroscope rotation to rotate a floating platform with a ball on it.
The problem i always encounter is: i can't lock the y axis. I used euler angles and it worked perfectly, but then i have to deal with gimbal lock. Because i don't want to deal with this issue of euler, i tried using quaternions instead and it does work in some kind of way.
I can set the rotation and can define a calibration offset for the gyroscope. If i wouldn't calculate this offset, the rotation would be absolute and not relative to the ingame world space. But i always have some sort of y rotation going on, even if i set it to 0 for the quaternion.

For example: i start the game, calibrate the gyro to my rotation but after that rotate around the y axis in real world space. The platform keeps facing the camera, but so doesn't the rotation axes.

The normal behaviour and how it always should be (no rotation on y axis in real world space):
https://www.nani-games.net/share/umSc6XH1vE.gif

The actual behaviour and how it shouldn't be (rotation on y axis in real world space):
https://www.nani-games.net/share/AVicmV4fWe.gif

**A list of what i already tried:**

- Using euler angles
- Using a combination of euler angles and quaternions in order to make up a new quaternion with desired parameters / rotations
- Using Quaternion.AngleAxis in order to change the order of the euler axes
- Checking the box "Freeze Y Rotation" of the platform's rigidbody under constraints (this doesn't work because i'm not applying force to rotate but rather set the rotation directly)

**How my scene is build up:**
https://www.nani-games.net/share/Unity_fAQKW7cfPK.png

I have two scripts which are used to get the gyroscope rotation, make it useful in unity and use it to rotate other objects.

**A static script called DeviceRotation. It activates the gyro and gets the rotation from it:**

```cs
using UnityEngine;

static class DeviceRotation
{
    public static Quaternion offsetRotation;

    private static bool gyroInitialized = false;

    public static bool HasGyroscope
    {
        get
        {
            return SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope;
        }
    }

    public static Quaternion Get()
    {
        if (!gyroInitialized)
        {
            InitGyro();
        }

        return HasGyroscope
            ? ReadGyroscopeRotation()
            : Quaternion.identity;
    }

    private static void InitGyro()
    {
        if (HasGyroscope)
        {
            Input.gyro.enabled = true;
            Input.gyro.updateInterval = 0.0167f; // 60Hz
        }
        gyroInitialized = true;
    }

    private static Quaternion ReadGyroscopeRotation()
    {
        return new Quaternion(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f) * Input.gyro.attitude * new Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0);
    }

    public static void calibrateCoords()
    {
        Quaternion deviceRotation = Get();
        offsetRotation = deviceRotation;
    }
}
```

**The second script which is appended to the platform object. It gets a calibration quaternion, calculates a new quaternion out of the calibration quaternion and a constantly updating quaternion (both taken from the gyroscopes rotation) and then sets the platforms transform to this new rotation:**

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Gyroscope : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button resetSphere;
    public Button calibrate;
    public GameObject sphere;

    public Text platformCoords;
    public Text gyroOffsetCoords;

    void Start()
    {
        DeviceRotation.calibrateCoords();
        calibrate.onClick.AddListener(DeviceRotation.calibrateCoords);

        setGyroRotation();
        resetSphere.onClick.AddListener(ResetSphere);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        setGyroRotation();

        Vector3 offsetRotationEuler = DeviceRotation.offsetRotation.eulerAngles;
        gyroOffsetCoords.text = "GyroOffset:\n" +
                                "X: " + offsetRotationEuler.x + "\n" +
                                "Y: " + offsetRotationEuler.y + "\n" +
                                "Z: " + offsetRotationEuler.z;
    }

    private void ResetSphere()
    {
        GameObject temp_sphere = Instantiate(sphere);
        temp_sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 3, 0);
    }

    private void setGyroRotation()
    {
        Quaternion deviceRotation = DeviceRotation.Get();
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(DeviceRotation.offsetRotation) * deviceRotation;
        transform.localRotation = newRotation;

        Vector3 platformAngles = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        platformCoords.text = "Platform:" + "\n" +
                              "X: " + platformAngles.x + "\n" +
                              "Y: " + platformAngles.y + "\n" +
                              "Z: " + platformAngles.z;
    }
}
```

So, to conclude everything: my problem is that i cannot lock one axis (the y axis) of a quaternion.
I also tried a combination of using euler to make the desired rotation i want and then converting it to a quaternion (that's why those two functions QuaternionToEuler and EulerToQuaternion exist in the script OffsetGyro), but unfortunately this caused gimbal lock (what a surprise i guess).

I really need help at this quaternion problem, i'm stuck with it since several days.

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark. Try adding this after you set the local rotation: `Vector3 desiredRelativeUp = transform.localRotation * Vector3.up;` `Vector3 desiredRelativeForward = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.right, desiredRelativeUp);` `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredRelativeForward, desiredRelativeUp);`  This will reorient `transform` so that its up axis exactly the same but with its right axis as aligned with the parent's right axis as possible.

Comment: @Ruzihm tried it like this ```Vector3 desiredRelativeUp = newRotation * Vector3.up;
        Vector3 desiredRelativeForward = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.right, desiredRelativeUp);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredRelativeForward, desiredRelativeUp); ``` but it doesn't do anything except causing gimbal lock when you rotate too far on the z axis. But still thanks for the idea!

Comment: Interesting... Please include an image showing the local axes of the transform when using the code in the question, the local axes of the parent, and the y axis you want to lock around (is it the world up direction, the up direction of the parent, or something else?)

Comment: Actually, if this is supposed to allow roaring more than 90 degrees in an axis...  what is the desired behaviors in these two situations: It flips 180 degrees around local x axis. 2) It flips 180 degrees around z axis? Should these result in the same orientation? They are exactly 180 degrees rotated around y axis from each other, which sounds like something you want to avoid.

Comment: The parent GyroOffset of the platform apparently doesn't do anything. It just holds a script for getting a calibration quaternion. The rotation of it stays the same and won't be changed by any script i have. The only rotation or transform changing is the one of the platform object. My problem is: playing the game and calibrating your rotation but then rotating around y axis in real world space shifts the rotation axes inside the game (visible in this [gif](https://www.nani-games.net/share/AVicmV4fWe.gif)). What can be seen here are the last recorded rotations => calibraction axes.

Comment: This [gif](https://www.nani-games.net/share/MKKVb0nYdK.gif) should make it a bit clearer, since i removed my improvised zeroing of the y axis of the quaternion. What i want is to lock the objects y rotation to be always 0, but using quaternions to avoid gimbal lock. I'm kind of already doing it by getting a static (not changing / updating) calibration quaternion, which i then subtract from the actual quaternion ```Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(DeviceRotation.offsetRotation) * deviceRotation;```

Comment: It should copy the rotation behaviour except the y rotation. So when i rotate my phone on x and z, the platform should do that too, but not when i rotate my phone on y, then the platform should be locked and not copy the rotation behviour. Because then [this would happen](https://www.nani-games.net/share/MKKVb0nYdK.gif)

Comment: I think I gave a bad example because I don't know for sure which physical axes on the phone map to the logical axes in code. Let me rephrase with "if the user flips their phone 180 degrees along the z axis,  then 180 degrees along the x axis, what orientation should the platform be? Keep in mind that the phone will be effectively rotated 180 degrees along the y axis from its original position, even though at no single moment was it physically rotated around the y axis"

Comment: Well, it's orientation should still be as it's original one, facing the camera even though it was theoretically rotated on the y axis but not practically.

Comment: Interesting. What if you start without the y axis fixing attempt then after you assign the current rotation, do `float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up); Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, transform.up); if (axis == Vector3.zero) { transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(transform.up.y>=0f? 0f: 180f, Vector3.right); } else { transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);}`

Comment: I did it like [this](https://www.nani-games.net/share/devenv_QpdhMNlhD4.png) and now the y rotation seems to be somewhat locked but rotating on the y axis still mixes up rotation axes like [this](https://www.nani-games.net/share/rWApaishES.gif). Basically rotating 90 degrees on real world space y axis "switches" the x and z rotation axes.

Comment: Ok, its not visible in the gif. Didnt think about it. But if i rotate on my chair about 90 degrees on the y axis, while playing the game, "switches" the x and z rotation axes. If i rotate my phone on the x axis physically it gets rotated on the z axis ingame etc.(atleast it looks like that). Hitting the calibrate button and updating the calibrate quaternion somewhat fixes the problem, but again just for the current rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i played with everything for a bit and tried to randomly create a possible solution. This is my current function setGyroRotation:

```cs
private void setGyroRotation()
{
    Quaternion deviceRotation = DeviceRotation.Get();
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(DeviceRotation.offsetRotation) * deviceRotation; // Calculating "initial" rotation
    axisObject.transform.rotation = newRotation; // Setting the axis' rotation to our "initial" rotation
    Vector3 unfixedUp = newRotation * Vector3.up;

    float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, unfixedUp);
    Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, unfixedUp);

    if (axis == Vector3.zero)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(unfixedUp.y >= 0f ? 0f : 180f, Vector3.right);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
    }

    Vector3 platformAngles = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    platformCoords.text = "Platform:" + "\n" +
                            "X: " + platformAngles.x + "\n" +
                            "Y: " + platformAngles.y + "\n" +
                            "Z: " + platformAngles.z;
}
```

It almost does work as expected: no gimbal lock (atleast not one which occurs easily. Only if you rotate your phone about 180 degrees on x or z) and y axis is freezed, but the initial / calibration rotation axes still are a big problem.
Here's a gif which hopefully displays the problem a bit better than the other ones:
https://www.nani-games.net/share/93eHK0Fz1t.gif

The axis above the platform displays the rotation of the gyro with an offset applied.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in comments:

```
// FIELDS
// device rotation from last frame
// init with DeviceRotation.Get() where appropriate
private Quaternion prevDeviceRotation; 

//...

// UPDATE LOGIC
// get the new device rotation
Quaternion newDeviceRotation = DeviceRotation.Get();

// Find difference between previous and current device rotation along previous axes
Quaternion relativeDelta = Quaternion.Inverse(prevDeviceRotation) * newDeviceRotation;

// Apply that difference to the transform's rotation to get an unfixed rotation 
// for the transform
Quaternion unfixedTransformRotation = transform.rotation * relativeDelta ;

// determine the unfixed up direction after that rotation is applied.
Vector3 unfixedUp = unfixedTransformRotation  * Vector3.up;

// find angle of up from world up
float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, unfixedUp); 
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, unfixedUp); 

// if up is colinear with world up, use identity or flipped rotation
if (axis == Vector3.zero) 
{ 
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(unfixedUp.y >= 0f ? 0f: 180f,
            Vector3.right); 
} 
else 
{ 
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
}

// update prevDeviceRotation
prevDeviceRotation = newDeviceRotation;
```

Comment: I tried it and it kind of seems to lock the y rotation, but theres a [new issue occuring when rotating too often on x and z axes](https://www.nani-games.net/share/BII0pdD3O2.gif). And when rotating physically on the y axis it tilts the platform a bit on the z axis.

Comment: @KoolerNolan  I'm curious about how to maybe fix the unwanted z rotation but for the instant reorientation, how else could rotating the platform 180 degrees around z then 180 degrees around x result in the platform returning to its original position if you don't have it re-rotate itself at some point along those two steps?

Comment: Isn't there another way of "locking" y rotation completely by using my code provided in the question? I'm using an offset quaternion which is updated by clicking a button. Using this offset already got me pretty far and i'm sure there isn't much left completing it.

Comment: @KoolerNolan It's still unclear about exactly what the desired behavior is...

Comment: the behaviour of the platforms rotation still should be that it's: always facing the camera, always rotates the same regardless of the physical rotation and has no gimbal lock. [The normal behaviour and how it always should be](https://www.nani-games.net/share/umSc6XH1vE.gif).
[The actual behaviour and how it shouldn't be (rotation on y axis in real world space)](https://www.nani-games.net/share/AVicmV4fWe.gif). The current problem i encounter is the second gif. If i rotate physically while i do ```newRotation.y = 0``` results in "shifted" rotation axes.

Comment: I think it would be best to use euler angles instead because of what you said earlier. I only want two rotation axes and basically erase the y axis. With euler it's much easier but then i don't know how to avoid gimbal lock.

Comment: This is what i initially wanted to do, but i discarded it because of gimbal lock: ```Quaternion deviceRotation = DeviceRotation.Get(); float xAngle = deviceRotation.eulerAngles.x - DeviceRotation.offsetRotation.eulerAngles.x; float zAngle = deviceRotation.eulerAngles.z - DeviceRotation.offsetRotation.eulerAngles.z; transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity * Quaternion.AngleAxis(zAngle, Vector3.forward) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(0f, Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(xAngle, Vector3.right);```